# mutlipart/form-data parsing error on Kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, multipart

I'm invoking the function `FormFile` on a standard `net/http` `Request` struct in my go server like so:

```
    multiFile, header, err := req.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("reader error: %s", err)
        // response error handling
        return
    }
```

When running locally using Docker Compose, this runs successfully, but when I run it on my Kubernetes cluster, I get the following error from my pod logs:

```
reader error: multipart: NextPart: read tcp [host]:[port]->[differentHost]:[differentPort]: i/o timeout
```

I've got a volume mounted to my pod to handle any writes to disk for overflowing buffers. Here's the relevant k8s deployment config:

```
    spec:
      containers:
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /tmp
              name: file-volume
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
        runAsGroup: 1000
        runAsUser: 1000
      volumes:
        - emptyDir: {}
          name: file-volume
```

Does anyone know what's causing this issue and how to fix?

Comment: do u have read timeout set in your server ?

Comment: Setting a long read timeout rather than using the default fixed it. If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll select it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set a long server time out this happens when we upload larger files/slower network connections

```
s := &http.Server{
    ReadTimeout:  150 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: 150 * time.Second,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A read timeout suggests that it is not so much an issue with your Pod internals, e.g. volume mounts, but a service discovery problem. The client does not seem to be able to read your Pod. Possibly, something to do with your K8s Service or Ingress configuration.

Alternatively, maybe your Pod does not run properly. In this case you would have to investigate the Pod logs and the K8s event log.

Comment: The pod is logging, and any the route is logging `fmt.Println` statements that come before the `FormFile` function is invoked. I'll look into potential gateway or ingress issues